# Pattern searching in Binaries

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, winapi

I read about some algorithms that can be used to find a string pattren in long text as fast as possible. I am looking for using `aho-corasick` algorithm in executable files, What functions or `win api` can be useful to make a binary ready to start searching?.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if an implementation of the Aho-Corasick algorithm was provided as part of Windows API.

Comment: Your question is overly broad and impossible to answer in its current form. The Aho-Corasick algorithm isn't particularly useful unless you're searching for occurrences of *multiple* patterns in a file. If you're looking for a single pattern, consider the Boyer-Moore algorithm. As for searching a binary file, you'll want to use standard I/O functions to open a file and read data into a buffer. The hard part is maintaining the buffer correctly so that searches can span buffer boundaries.

Comment: I would to implement AC myself, I am asking about api that are useful to implement AC search. Do I need to map the files in the memory first or what exactly!

Comment: Since the algorithm doesn't seem to ever go back, all you'd need is to read in from std::ifstream one character at a time, and it automagically does all the work for you.

Comment: "and it automagically does all the work for you"... but to be as fast as possible it is good to ask ifstream to read not a byte-by-byte, but to read some char array, sized several kilobytes, e.g. 4 kb or 16 kb. This will lower number of automagic actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one free C++ implementation for Windows: [link](http://www.komodia.com/aho-corasick/) (look for "Aho-Corasick source code" towards the bottom of the page).